# VMExtensionProvisioningError:Timeout

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure ARM Template that should create a Linux VM by installing custom extensions from azure storage blob.

After Linux VM is installed, I need to run a custom script using Azure's `CustomScriptForLinux`. Therefore, the second script should depend on the `MicrosoftScriptExtension` installation. Here is an example that shows how I tried to write that in an ARM template:

```
{
        "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/', parameters('availabilitySetName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "availabilitySet": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('availabilitySetName'))]"
            },
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "dataDisks": "[take(variables('diskArray'), parameters('numDataDisks'))]",
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[variables('images')[parameters('osType')].publisher]",
                    "offer": "[variables('images')[parameters('osType')].offer]",
                    "sku": "[variables('images')[parameters('osType')].sku]",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmDnsName'),'-osDisk')]",
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
                    },
                    "createOption": "FromImage"
                }
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [{
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
                }]
            }
        },
        "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('vmScriptExtensionName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publisher": "[variables('extension')[parameters('os')].scriptExtensionPublisher]",
                "type": "[variables('extension')[parameters('os')].scriptExtensionType]",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "[variables('extension')[parameters('os')].scriptExtensiontypeHandlerVersion]",
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                        "[variables('scriptURI')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURI_installchef_data_bag_secret')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURI_installchef_data_bag_secret_flc')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURI_installchef_data_bag_secret_dct')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURI_installchef_data_bag_secret_powershell')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURIsetup')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURIsetupFLC')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURIsetupDCT')]",
                        "[variables('scriptURIpartition')]"
                    ],
                    "commandToExecute": "[variables('extension')[parameters('os')].scriptExtensionCommand]"
                },
                "protectedSettings": {
                    "storageAccountName": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountName')]",
                    "storageAccountKey": "[parameters('customScriptStorageAccountKey')]"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extension')[parameters('os')].chefExtensionName)]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions', variables('vmName'), variables('vmScriptExtensionName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "publisher": "Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure",
            "type": "[variables('extension')[parameters('os')].chefExtensionName]",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1210.12",
            "settings": {
                "bootstrap_options": {
                    "chef_node_name": "[variables('vmName')]",
                    "chef_server_url": "[parameters('chef_server_url')]",
                    "validation_client_name": "[parameters('validation_client_name')]",
                    "node_ssl_verify_mode": "none",
                    "environment": "[parameters('chef_environment')]"
                },
                "runlist": "[parameters('runlist')]",
                "bootstrap_version": "12.19.36",
                "validation_key_format": "[parameters('validation_key_format')]",
                "client_rb": "ssl_verify_mode :verify_none\nverify_api_cert false\n#"
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
                "validation_key": "[parameters('validation_key')]",
                "secret": "[parameters('data_bag_secret')]"
            }
        }
    }
```

If I run this ARM template, I get the error

> Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions 'VMName/MicrosoftScriptExtension' failed with message '{
>     "status": "Failed",
>     "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>       "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
>           "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'MicrosoftScriptExtension'. Error message: \"Enable failed: processing file downloads failed: failed to download file[0]: failed to download file: http request failed: Get https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/vm-disk-utils-RAID0.sh?se=2018-05-07T16%3A08%3A22Z&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXX%3D&sp=r&sr=b&sv=2015-02-21: dial tcp: i/o timeout\"."
>         }
>       ]
>     }

I don't understand why?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: how big are your files in the blob storage ? it seems that getting this file fails `vm-disk-utils-RAID0.sh`

Comment: @Thomas, The size of the file is less than 1 MB

Comment: Are you able to access the file using this url ? It is possible that the sas token expired ?

Comment: yes, I am able to access the file using the above URL

Comment: The above extensions should be installed when using simple virtual network with default subnet. but when I use the virtual network having nsg's, route table and subnets, then I am getting above error.